# Help Grounding LED Mirror

Tags: wiring, led, light, mirror

I'm attempting to install this LED mirror. It has standard black, white and green wires. However the light fixture which I'm trying to replace with LED mirror has ground exposed wire run between the light fixture and it's own wall plate. I'm not sure where to connect the green wire from the mirror once the wall plate of the original light is gone.

Any suggestions are be appreciated

[image: new led mirror wires][image: wall plate and light fixture with current wiring]

Comment: the box itself should be grounded.

Comment: I believe the box is made of plastic. Should I replace the box to a metal one?

Comment: some places (eg chicago) now want metal boxes, so that's not a bad idea, but if there's an incoming ground, mating it with the case or ground lead should suffice for safety purposes.

Answer (score 0):

At this point of disassembly I cannot tell for sure, but I suspect that the ground is either connected to the box or the backside of the fixture. the existing mid fixture ground is the bare wire attached to the green screw. I would take it a little further apart and verify that there is a metal box or a ground wire attached to a mid bracket  behind the fixture back.

Answer (score 0):

Many homes were built with out grounds depending on the age of the home there may not be a ground.

Adding a ground is code compliant and has been for several cycles if there is a ground that you have access to and it originates in the same panel.

The metal frame work may have had a green screw but if it was not connected to a metal box through metal conduit (one method of grounding) OR a grounded conductor, usually a bare copper wire in the back of your box you do not have a ground.

Non conductive fixtures regularly do not have grounds at the lamp and your fixture may be one like that where it doesn’t really matter we ground when we can but in pre 70’s homes many homes do not have grounds.

I don’t have a ground and would like to have one. This is easily taken care of if there is another circuit in the area coming from the same panel connecting that ground to this one with a separate bare or insulated conductor of the appropriate size can be done.